# Android - Update Bitmap When the View Has Been Measured

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am trying to retrieve a bitmap from an image view and then scale it. But I am getting the error below:

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0"

As ı searched the internet it is because before the imageView finishes to be measured and converted to bitmap, I try to update the bitmap. Could anybody help me abouy how I can fix this. My code is as below:

```
profileImage.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = profileImage.getDrawingCache();

int widthPixel = bm.getWidth();
int heightPixel = bm.getHeight();
int basePixel;
float widthRatio;
float heightRatio;

if (widthPixel < heightPixel) {
  basePixel = widthPixel;
}
else {
   basePixel = heightPixel;
}

if (basePixel > 180) {
  widthRatio = 180/basePixel;
  heightRatio = 180/basePixel;
}
else {
   widthRatio = 1;
   heightRatio = 1;
}

Bitmap bmResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,(int)(bm.getWidth()*widthRatio), (int)(bm.getHeight()*heightRatio), true);
// bm.recycle();

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmResized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byteArray1 = stream.toByteArray();
```

Edited Code (now getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value may not be null." error):

```
                                    profileImage.buildDrawingCache();
                                    bm = profileImage.getDrawingCache();



                                    profileImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
                                        public boolean onPreDraw() {
                                            profileImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                                            widthPixel = profileImage.getMeasuredWidth();
                                            heightPixel = profileImage.getMeasuredHeight();

                                            if (widthPixel < heightPixel) {

                                                basePixel = widthPixel;

                                            }

                                            else {

                                                basePixel = heightPixel;

                                            }


                                            if (basePixel > 180) {

                                                widthRatio = 180/basePixel;
                                                heightRatio = 180/basePixel;


                                            }

                                            else {

                                                widthRatio = 1;
                                                heightRatio = 1;

                                            }


                                            Bitmap bmResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,(int)(bm.getWidth()*widthRatio), (int)(bm.getHeight()*heightRatio), true);
                                            // bm.recycle();

                                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                            bmResized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                                            byteArray1 = stream.toByteArray();

                                            image1 = new ParseFile("profilePhoto.jpg", byteArray1, "image/jpg");

                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [OnPreDrawListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html). The `OnPreDrawListener` allows you to retrieve your View dimensions after your View's measure operation, but before the layout phase. This means this is the earliest possible time where you can fetch your View dimensions.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().adOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);


        int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();

        // TODO scale your bitmap here

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello Reiner, I edited my code as above with the "OnPreDrawListener", but now I am getting the "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value may not be null." error. May you check my code above? Thank you.

Comment: Whenever your application crashes with an Exception, look up the line number that is mentioned. This will point you towards the line in your code where the error is taking place, so you can debug the issue. Since you mention that the error being thrown is an `IllegalArgumentException` and the message reads `value may not be null`, I'm guessing you're trying to resize a `null` Bitmap.

Comment: @saner There's some problems with your approach. You're trying to render a View's  drawing-cache into a `Bitmap`. However, the View has not yet been drawn, so the View's drawing-cache is empty, making `view.getDrawingCache()` to return `null`. Either force the View to draw (plenty of examples on SO), or take another approach. One alternative would be to call `view.getDrawable()`, then convert the `Drawable` to a Bitmap, which you can then resize.

Comment: Hello Reiner, in my edited code above, after putting the first two lines in my addPreDrawListener part  it started to work. Thank you very much.